# Finding the equation of an ellipse centered at (-1,3) and through the points (1,3) and (-1,4)

Tags: conic-sections

I've been taking a computer graphics class and as a review we had some questions about some geometric problems. This one I can not seem to figure out though it seems that it should be straight forward.

I know that the standard equation of an ellipse is

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
```

From this we shift to its stated center and the equation becomes

```
(x+1)^2/a^2 + (y-3)^2/b^2 =1
```

But from here I am at a loss for where to go from here...

Comment: Draw a picture of your ellipse. Remember that in your equation, $a$ is the length from the center of the ellipse to its rightmost point and $b$ is the length from the centre to its lowest point. You can see what those should be.

Comment: Plug the coordinates of the given points into your equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute into your second equation (corrected with $b^2$ in the second denominator) the $x, y$ values for each of the points on the ellipse $(1, 3), (-1, 4)$, and you'll obtain two equations in two unknowns, from which you can solve for $a^2$ and $b^2$.

That is, evaluate $$\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y-3)^2}{b^2} =1$$

at (1) $(1, 3)$ and again at (2) $(-1, 4)$. That will give you two equations in $a^2, b^2$, for which you can solve simultaneously.

$$\dfrac{(1 + 1)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(3-3)^2}{b^2} = 1 \implies \dfrac 4{a^2} = 1 \implies a^2 = 4\tag{1}$$

$$\dfrac{(-1 + 1)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(4-3)^2}{b^2} = 1 \implies \dfrac 1{b^2} = 1 \implies b^2 = 1\tag{2}$$

Now, use the general equation with your new-found values for $a^2, b^2$.

Comment: from the given three conditions, how can we assume that the axes of the ellipse are parallel to the Cartesian axes?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee There is only one ellipse with a given center passing through two specified points, so any ellipse you find satisfying those conditions is the only one.

Comment: @RagibZaman, how can we establish the uniqueness?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You're making this much more difficult than it needs to be!

Comment: God created all ellipses with their axes parallel  to x and y axes. It was the mathematicians who twisted things.

Comment: Hahaha, I like that, @Maesumi!

Comment: @amWhy, why don't you supply direct answer if you have one?

Comment: @amWhy: Another TU +1